# Joomla for Azure Website with azuresql database seems broken

Tags: joomla, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to create a joomla website on Azure websites using the install from the app gallery.

The first problems I had were the /tmp folder and /var/logs has to be changed. After that was fine I tried installing a template but I had to make a .user.ini file to set the upload limits higher.

When trying to install the theme it signs me out of joomla and signing in returns to the extension installer page with just the joomla banner. I have to sign out and sign in to get back into administration page.

Everything seems broken. Am I configuring this wrong or is Joomla for windows Azure broken for everyone?

Comment: Is the template available online? If so, could you point me to it? If not, could you give some size estimates so that I can attempt to reproduce?

Comment: try uploading the template to the FTP and installing from the directory

Comment: @SyntaxC4 its from rockettheme.

Comment: @Lodder, it doesn't matter if i ftp in the file to the tmp directory or remote. It will still sign me out. It also doesnt matter if it is a template or a module it will still sign me out.

Comment: hmm I was going to say, try installing [Admin Forever](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/11476) which prevents an admin from being logged out but you can't install it. You could always try installing this plugin manually, and by that I mean uploading the files to the plugins folder and adding it manually to PHPmyAdmin